# how can i record android touch event /dev/input/event on a rooted device?

Tags: android

I hope capture using adb shell get touch information in application

so i tested this method

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();

os.write(("getevent|grep event2").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = null;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
Log.d("Service", line);
}
```

this method operation good one line, but i need to continuous feedback like Android service

how can i get information that is being output? when i send "adb shell getevent"

thank for advice!

Comment: Try it without the grep as you can do that easily from the java side (possibly it is going into block buffered mode)

Comment: I don't understand without grep, only remove grep method? please describe as detail, and how can i continuous get data?

Comment: grep can have buffering behavior which could be a problem without additional setting, so try it without.  If you are able to get a continuing stream of lines, filtering them in java is trivial.